# What are the meanings of dot in word what show in Oxford Dictionary advanced learners for mobile?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, dictionaries

What are the meanings of dot in word what show in Oxford Dictionary advanced learners for mobile (licensed subscription)?

[image]

Example word: `ability` . Web version of Oxford dictionary for advanced learners has not this dot. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ability_1?q=ability .

Why it is not `a - bi - li - ty`? What are benefit of this dot for English learners?

Related link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oup.elt.oald10_gp

Comment: I'd guess it indicates hyphenation (abil-ity), but you should check the documentation.

Comment: I see stress mark at `b`, I don't understand why it is not `a-BIL-ity` . Stress mark made dot character irrationale, and I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

They are word division dots.

From [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/word-division-dots-and-syllable-pronunciation-hyphens),

> Within a dictionary entry, the dots that break up a word are known as
> end-of-line division dots. These dots indicate where the word can be
> broken if it doesn't fit on a line of text.

The word *ability* therefore according to this system, can be broken down (while writing not reading and only if there are no spaces left in the same line) as: *abil-ity* and cannot be as *a-bility* or *abili-ty*

Also see [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606670/where-should-one-place-word-division-dots-in-schroedinger-with-oe-instead-o) english SE post

Comment: But why are these word division dots present in the mobile version of the dictionary and not in the web version? Is there a way to enable/disable them? Does the dictionary have anywhere explaining them?